# Webhook Activity runs forever in ADF V2

Tags: powershell, webhooks, azure-data-factory, azure-automation

I want to process my cube through runbook where I have written the code in Power Shell.I want to call this runbook from the webhook activity from ADF.But this activity is running until the timeout and could not complete however its processing the cube successfully by triggering the run book. Do I have to write some more code in order to make it successful or fail in ADF. or am I missing something else in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for ADF to wait until the runbook completes than a Webhook activity (like you are doing) is right. But your runbook needs to take in the callbackUri parameter using the [$webhookData parameter in the Azure Automation webhook documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks?#parameters-used-when-the-webhook-starts-a-runbook). And the runbook needs to make a Web call back to the ADF callback API to let it know it’s done.

On the other hand if you don’t want ADF to wait or know whether the runbook failed then use a Web Activity rather than a Webhook activity.

If you proceed with an ADF webhook, then you will need to change your Azure Automation runbook to include the following parameter and parsing:

```
param(
    [object] $WebhookData
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

try
{
    #parse the webhook parameters
    if (-Not $WebhookData.RequestBody)
    {
        #we're testing in the test pane
        $WebhookData = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData
    }
    $WebhookBody = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody
    [string] $callbackUri = $WebhookBody.callbackUri

    #complete your typical runbook work here...

    if ($callbackUri)
    {
        $null = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $callbackUri -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"StatusCode": "200"}' -UseBasicParsing
    }

}
catch 
{
    if ($callbackUri)
    {
        $null = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $callbackUri -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"StatusCode": "500", "Error": {"ErrorCode":100,"Message","$_"}}' -UseBasicParsing
    }
    "Failed: $_"
    throw $_
}
```

That should solve your problem with ADF thinking the runbook runs forever.